# using Python pyodbc to read from database and handoff to Matlab using pointers

Tags: python, matlab, memory-management, odbc, pyodbc

I am using Python to read a large amount of data from a MySql database using Python's database package, pyodbc.  I pass the sql statement using cursor.execute(sqlStatement) and read it out using cursor.fetchall().

I am passing it into Matlab by writing it to a .mat file with the scipy package.

However, since it is a very large amount of data, I would like to skip the part of writing it into a .mat file and read it out directly from memory in Matlab.  is there any way to do this?

Comment: MatLab can connect directly to SQL Server over ODBC to perform the query itself, AFAIK. While I love Python, I don't think its necessary here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/database/ug/connecting-to-a-database-using-the-native-odbc-interface.html

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
For row in cursor.fetchAll():
    #send each fetched row to Matlab here
```

I'm not entirely familiar with Matlab; can it listen on a socket?

If so, it would be something like this, assuming you've already created your cursor connection:

```
cursor.execute(sqlStatement)    

socket = socket()

try:
    socket.connect((MATLAB_SERVER, PORT))
except: 
    print("Couldn't connect, are server and port available?")
    sys.exit(1)

For row in cursor.fetchall():
    #send each fetched row to Matlab here
    socket.sendall(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t have the database toolbox you can also run the python code inside Matlab:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/install-supported-python-implementation.html#bujjwjn

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30052302)